# SQL Server 2008: Large transaction log file in Simple Recovery Mode

Tags: sql-server-2008, transaction-log

I am having a problem with disk space in SQL Server 2008.
This is the situation:
- I had a DB set with Simple Recovery and this DB used to use 2-3 GB for the transaction log file
- I moved this DB to a new server and the situation was the same
- I changed the recovery mode to FULL and, rightly, the log got 20 GB of disk space
- I changed the recovery mode back to SIMPLE and I am not able to shrink the log file back to the 2-3 GB of disk space

The log file is very big and is growing fast.

I've verified and in the log file there is no room, in fact "available free space" is near 0%.

Can anyone help me please?

Thank you very  much,
Enrico

=============================================================

### Till I can't add comments, I will add here the SOLUTION:

Thanks to adaptr answer a foung the solution.

visit this forum post:
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic695034-357-1.aspx#bm1377968

the steps I followed are:

1)SELECT log_reuse_wait_desc FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'yourdb'
--> the result was REPLICATION

2)EXEC sp_removedbreplication [yourdb]
--> then execute SELECT log_reuse_wait_desc FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'yourdb'
----> the result was NOTHING

2a)(ALTER DATABASE msdb SET RECOVERY SIMPLE)
--> I did not run this, but may be someone could need it

3)SHRINK the DB log file
--> now the log file is correctly back to less than 1GB

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following to see why the log can't be re-used:

```
SELECT log_reuse_wait_desc FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'yourdb'
```

See [**this article**](http://vismit.khapre.org/2006/08/logreusewaitdesc-column-in_23.aspx) for possible reasons.